# Unable to run php script using cron

Tags: php, cron

I am running a php script using cron. The name of the file is : PriceChecker.php . 
This is my cron script

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 07,11,16,20 * * * php /var/www/mainsite/PriceChecker.php
* * * * * /var/www/mainsite/pricecheck.sh
```

The shell script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
php PriceChecker.php >logger.log
```

The first line is the original. The second is for testing
I have tried various variations including: /usr/bin/php /var/www/mainsite/PriceChecker.php

If I log the out in the cron php /var/www/mainsite/PriceChecker.php > logfile.log

The logfile is created, but is empty

Comment: Guessing without knowing anything else about scripts? I don't think you'll find an answer here :)

Comment: When you debug line-by-line the `PriceChecker.php`, at what lines does the code break? And what is written in the error log?

Comment: What is your script about ? Are you sure it isn't executed ? What is the expected output ? Try to log something on a file using your PHP script itself.

Comment: It's always safer to refer to the php binary with an absolute path (like `/usr/bin/php` - execute `where php` to figure out what to use).  Reason is that typically cron offers very little PATH to the tasks it runs.

Comment: I did that. I used /usr/bin/php. Didnt work

Comment: Okay, waht worked was changind directory to script directly before execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay what worked was CDing into the directory of the script

https://serverfault.com/questions/97828/php-from-command-line-path-problems/97881#97881

Answer (score 2):

Same as here, I think [Cannot get PHP cron script to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972690/cannot-get-php-cron-script-to-run?rq=1)

You forgot to specify the user name you want your script to be run as.

Comment: root. The same username as the one setting the cron, in my case root

Comment: You don't need it if you use `crontab -u myUser -e`

Comment: Right. As said before; full paths are better, try to run your script in a root terminal to test it

Comment: it works when i run it in the terminal. I am using the following pricechecker.sh : `/usr/bin/php /var/www/mainsite/PriceChecker.php >/var/www/mainsite/logger.log`

Comment: Like I said : try to log something on a file using your PHP script itself.

Comment: Since the log file is created, the cron job actually runs. you should check /var/log/syslog

Comment: Th cron job does run, and it seems the pricechecker.sh is executed because I added two echos before and after the script. The php line also is executed (since the php log is generated too), but no output is logged. Nor is the database affected in any way

Comment: This /var/www/ thing seems weird for a cron job. Try storing your script elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the full path of the PHP file to be execute

Comment: that wasn't the issue. I mentioned that I used the full path in the answer