# Bash script sends email even when it shouldn't

Tags: bash, email, debian-jessie, tripwire

I have a cron job run by root every hour that checks if there's a tripwire violation. It still sends me an email every hour, whether I have a violation or not. If there is a violation, it includes the report. If there is no violation, it sends me a blank email with just the subject line.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save report
tripwire --check > /tmp/twreport

# Count violations
v=`grep -c 'Total violations found:  0' /tmp/twreport`

# Send report
if [ "$v" -eq 0 ]; then
        mail -s "[tripwire] Report for `uname -n`" user@example.com < /tmp/twreport
fi
```

Comment: If it's sending a blank email, that seems to indicate `/tmp/twreport` is empty. That would certainly result in `v` being set to zero. Suggest you debug what actually gets written to that file.

Comment: The file is written to - it either shows 0 violations or x number of violations. The v is either 0 or 1. When I run it manually it works fine, only in cron does it not work.

Comment: There is a vast difference in environment between terminals and cron jobs so that may be the issue here. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972690/cannot-get-php-cron-script-to-run/1972763#1972763

Comment: Ah, I don't have the full path to tripwire in the script. I've added it in and will see if it executes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the code to

```
if [ -f /tmp/twreport ] # Check file exists
then
 v=$(grep -c '^Total violations found:  0$' /tmp/twreport)
 #Not suggested using legacy backticks
 if [ "$v" -eq 0 ]; then
        mail -s "[tripwire] Report for $(uname -n)" user@example.com < /tmp/twreport
 fi
fi
```

Finally set the path in cron before you put the script line. like

```
# Setting PATH
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/path/to/tripwire:/and/so/on
# Now,set up the cron-job for the script
0        11         *              *          0       /path/to/script
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding with double quotes and use full path

```
v="`/bin/grep -c 'Total violations found:  0' /tmp/twreport`"
```

and

```
if [ "$v" == "0" ]; then # or = instead of == based on your shell
```

If these don't work verify the search term. I see two spaces before 0 on 'found:  0'

Comment: The use of `"` quotes is not an issue here since `grep -c` always outputs a number (no spaces or other weird stuff that quotes would fix).